# How to find multiple array elements by value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to select multiple array elements that have the same value.
Using **array.find ()** returns only the first element that satisfies the query condition.
The construction below shows only "Donald Trump" in console:

```
const data = [
  {
    "position": "president",
    "name": "Donald Trump",
    "language": "english"
  },
  {
    "position": "president",
    "name": "Vladimir Putin",
    "language": "russian"
  },
  {
    "position": "king",
    "name": "Shutruk-Nahhunte",
    "language": "elamite"
  },
];
let result = data.find(elem => elem.position == "president");
console.log(result.name);
```

But I need to get all the values as an array, - something like this:

```
[
  "Donald Trump",
  "Vladimir Putin"
]
```

How to do it right, considering also that the real array is huge.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use filter to do this task

```js
const data = [
  {
    "position": "president",
    "name": "Donald Trump",
    "language": "english"
  },
  {
    "position": "president",
    "name": "Vladimir Putin",
    "language": "russian"
  },
  {
    "position": "king",
    "name": "Shutruk-Nahhunte",
    "language": "elamite"
  },
];

const newArray= data.filter(x=>x.position==='president')
let nameArray=newArray.map(x=>x.name)
console.log(nameArray)
```